# Question on topic regarding implications of being an independent contractor or an employee in Belgium?

Tags: discussion

I've run into the scenario where sometimes employees are opting to be independent contractors in Belgium vs. a normal employee, and I'm trying to understand the advantages/disadvantages of doing so.

I'm not sure if this type of question is appropriate for this site and am looking for clarification.

Comment: Depends on how and what you ask on your question... I don't see one in your post. Do you have a phrasing in mind so we can better help you find its on-topicness?... my partial answer given the description you say I would think it is ok and on-topic. Phrasings that come to mind are of the form *"[...]. What implications does it have to be independent contractor in Belgium? Are there any advantages in doing so compared to a 'regular' employment?"*

Comment: Since I gather you're mostly asking about the financial advantages, it's potentially more a question for [money.se], assuming it's on-topic there (not entirely sure). While we cover negotiations around compensation and do regularly have questions around benefits and so on, a detailed analysis of a particular country's various fiscal constructions and loopholes when it comes to employment is probably beyond our scope. As someone from Belgium who looked into this before, I'm not sure I'd even be able to answer this. You might get more useful advice on forums dedicated to Belgium.

Comment: Yes I was mainly interested in the financial implications of being a contractor in Belgium vs. not from the employees' perspective. Based on @Lilienthal resp. I'm thinking that the financial angle would be OffT here.